# Error accessing function of class while converting Obj C project to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, porting

I added my swift class to the target while removing my header file of the same objective C class from the target but this error shows when I try and build my project. I can't attach an image right now but the error states: "Use of instance member 'url' on type 'ServerURLFactory'; did you mean to use a value of type 'ServerURLFactory' instead?"

```
    let accessURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(ServerURLFactory.url())/CygnetInstanceXMLServlet?cygnetId=\(idNumber)")!

    print(accessURL)
```

Has anyone ran into a similar problem and how to fix this confusing bug? Its as if the program is still trying to call the Obj C function instead of explicitly calling the one in the Swift file.

Comment: When I use the obj C target instead of the Swift one, the project builds and runs fine. The swift class has the same url function as the obj c one but for some reason it has problems calling it.

Comment: Yes, it is a class.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the build error. Must've been a different between the objective C porting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.url()` on `ServerURLFactory` itself as a type:

```
ServerURLFactory.url()
```

I guess you should instantiate the class first. Probably something like this, but it depends on how the class is implemented:

```
let factory = ServerURLFactory()
```

Then:

```
factory.url()
```